# gvim font too wide on docker container

Tags: vim, fonts

Why does gvim guifont look too wide, or "interfont" space too wide, regardless of which one I choose?

Instead of looking like this: [image: gvim in host machine]

It looks like this: [image: gvim in docker container]

#### What I've tried

1. I checked the installed fonts into the docker container:

```
$ fc-list | grep -i light
/usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSans-ExtraLight.ttf: DejaVu Sans,DejaVu Sans Light:style=ExtraLight
$
```

Then I try such font on gvim:
[image: set guifont=*]

But it still looks wider than the [image: preview]. Same thing if I try with another font.

So, what do I need to do to make it look like the first screenshot?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Where to start?

In the first screenshot, the name of the font in use is clearly visible: *Inconsolata*. If you want another GVim to look like that one, you will **rather obviously** need the same font. If you don't have it, then install it.

As for why your attempts were unsuccessful… fonts basically exist in two kinds:

- "Variable-width", where each glyph has its own metrics and the spacing between two glyphs can also be adjusted on a case-by-case basis.

  These fonts are optimised for reading in a natural way, where your eyes follow the *horizontal* flow of the text. They are the default fonts used in word processors, web pages, or books.
- "Fixed-width" (or "monospaced"), where all glyphs have the exact same metrics and no attempt is made to adjust spacing between glyphs.

  These fonts are optimised for being displayed in a grid, with each glyph perfectly aligned horizontally and vertically with the others, allowing your eyes to process text in both directions, following alignments, patterns, etc. They are the default fonts used in terminal emulators and programming text editors/IDEs.

GVim being nothing more than a glorified and extremely specialised terminal emulator, it only knows how to display text in a grid so it only really works with monospaced fonts like Inconsolata. Tell it to use a variable-width font and you get a mess.

DejaVu Sans being a variable-width font, you get the only possible outcome. If you choose *Monospace* from that font chooser you should get a usable, at least, setup.